Spring Boot 2.7.18 compatibility issue with spring-cloud
I am trying to upgrade my project to spring boot 2.7.18. I am using Spring cloud version 2021.0.9. But when I run my project I get below error

Description:
Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to
following reasons:

Spring Boot [2.7.18] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Action:
Consider applying the following actions:

Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.4.x, 2.5.x] . You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn].  If you want to learn
more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit
this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check
the [Release Trains] section. If you want to disable this check, just
set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]


As per this compatibility guide,  2021.0.x aka Jubilee of cloud should be compatible with spring boot 2.6.x, 2.7.x (Starting with 2021.0.3). Then why I am getting this error. I don't want to downgrade my Spring Boot, neither do I want to upgrade to version 3. If I have to use Spring Boot 2.7.18, what is the way forward?
Below is my POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.seqnc</groupId>
    <artifactId>subscription-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>subscription-service</name>
    <description>Subscription service - Chargebee library</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.9</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-doc-version>2.6.0</spring-doc-version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-doc-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>subscription-service</finalName>
    </build>

</project>


Please share your pom.xml

Hi, can you please post the main parts of your pom.xml file, to check if there are some dependency clash? Compatibility betveen Spring Cloud 2021.0.9 and Spring Boot 2.7.18 is also shown here: https://spring.io/blog/2023/12/20/spring-cloud-2021-0-9-aka-jubilee-is-now-available

@Silviu Burcea updated POM

@FrancescoPoli I removed the non spring jars from POM . Please check. Yes as per the doc I am using compatible versions for both. But still I get this error

You have spring-cloud.version defined but you don't import the spring-cloud-dependencies BOM.

Try adding the following in pom.xml file, and remove the version tag from spring-cloud-starter-* dependencies.
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


As our Friends mention You have to check which version of spring-cloud to match you spring-boot
I will just add with how you can check for the lates from this URL
With Example Gradle or maven from official Spring
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview

